# Publish RMarkdown Created Posts on WordPress

Tags: r, wordpress, r-markdown, knitr, xml-rpc

How do I publish RMarkdown created posts on WordPress. I've set things up with

```
library(RWordPress)
library(knitr)

options(WordpressLogin = c(my.wp_userid = 'my. wp_password'),
        WordpressURL = '<http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/xmlrpc.php')
```

To publish a new post, I run

```
knit2wp(<TITLE>.Rmd', 
        title = '<TITLE>',
        publish = TRUE, 
        action = "newPost")
```

When I try to publish the new post (created in R markdown) to WordPress I get the following error message:

```
Error in xml.rpc(.server, method, as.character(blogid), names(login), : Problems
```

And here's how I've tried to update a post

```
knit2wp('<TITLE>.Rmd', 
        title = '<TITLE>',
        publish = TRUE, 
        action = "editPost",
        postid = 500)
```

And when I try to update the existing post on WordPress using R Markdown, I get the following error message:

```
Error in xml.rpc(.server, "metaWeblog.editPost", as.character(postid), : Problems
```

Answer (score 0):

When you log into Wordpress, look for the Media tab. After you click the Media link, you can choose the option to upload a new page. After the content uploads, you can click on the newly uploaded page to see the URL for the new content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have finally troubleshot the issue. Actually I was making a mistake while providing the URL. To my understanding, the correct URL must end at project name (i.e. WordPress in my case) before the mandatory part xmlrpc.php. More specifically,

The correct URL may comprise of three parts:

1. wp_hosting server (external/local): (e.g. local: "http://localhost/" and external: https://www.example.com/)
2. wp_project name: (e.g. "wordpress")
3. mandatory part: ("xmlprc.php")

So, the correct URL in my case is http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php' while I was incorrectly writing it http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/xmlrpc.php' and including my wp-username (which is admin) in the URL.